# Combining tags from children in Umbraco

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, umbraco

I have a blog section on a Umbraco site, where I want to get all tags from each blog item and combine them in a list without dublicates, so that I can use the taglist as a filter.

I have this section where tags will be listed

```
<ul id="blogTags" class="inline-list">
   <li class="tag-item"><a href="#">Tag 1</a></li>
   <li class="tag-item"><a href="#">Tag 2</a></li>
   <li class="tag-item"><a href="#">Tag 3</a></li>
   <li class="tag-item"><a href="#">Tag 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

On my BlogItem doctype I have a field `tagsList` where the editor can input a comma-separated list of tags.

So basically I want to get all tags from all BlogItems and combine them into a list where dublicates are removed.

I am getting all blog items using:

```
 var blogItems = Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Content.Id).Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "BlogItem" && x.IsVisible());
```

But I am not sure how to get all tags, combine and remove dublicates.

Comment: what type is `tagsList` - a textstring or ?

Comment: tagsList is a textstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of doing it is create a Hashset to store tags and use foreach to add it.

so you can do something like:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueTagList = new HashSet<string>();

var blogItems = Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Content.Id).Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "BlogItem" && x.IsVisible());

var tags = blogItems.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("tagsList"));

foreach(var tag in tags)
{
    var splitTag = tag.Split(',');
    foreach(var singleTag in splitTag)
    {
        uniqueTagList.Add(singleTag);
    }
}
```

then your `uniqueTagList` is a list of all the tag, which you can use to create your list

```
<ul id="blogTags" class="inline-list">
    @foreach(var tag in uniqueTagList)
    {
        <li class="tag-item"><a href="#">@tag</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

but beware that if you have a lot of children, this can take some time.

So I would suggest checkout Umbraco tag data type to do something like this:

https://shermandigital.com/blog/display-umbraco-tags-on-razor-templates/

https://shermandigital.com/blog/get-umbraco-content-by-tag/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a comma separated list, you could use the built in Umbraco tagging controls, which should allow you to do what you're after.

There are API methods for the tags that allow you to get al the tags for specific groups etc. So you could set up a tag property editor with a group called "blog" that you can assign to your blog posts, and then you can use the Tags API to pull out all of the unique tags from that group to build your cloud.